# Cloudfront.net Main Thread Blocking Time?

Tags: javascript, performance, amazon-cloudfront, lighthouse

My web app uses cloudfront.net as a CDN. Google Lighthouse is saying it adds 598ms to my main-thread blocking time:

[image]

Does Lighthouse mean that cloudfront.net could be accessed in a non-render-blocking way? Or is it just saying that other components of my web app, which are being loaded via the CDN, need to be addressed separately to reduce the blocking time that those individual components contribute?

Comment: Nothing to do with CloudFront; the assets you're loading *from* CloudFront are what block. That 5bd3c55....js file; presumably part of your app?

Comment: Okay, yes, I think that is my app.  I've already lazy-loaded everything I can. I'll keep looking for ways to reduce the size of my initial app bundle.  Does it sound like I have the correct analysis of what needs to be done?

Comment: Lighthouse is saying that my total blocking time is 230ms, which I understand is pretty good. So based on that, I guess blocking time isn't a big factor. I have to figure out what else I can do to get my Lighthouse score into the 90+ range!

Comment: If you'd like to post your comment in the form of an answer, I can mark it as the accepted answer.